# Can a Kineticist/Rogue Delayed Blast work with Flurry of Blast and Many Throw and sneak attack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I know a version of this question was asked earlier, but this is the next evolutionary step of this tactic.

Can a Kineticist/Rogue Delayed Blast work with Flurry of Blast and Many Throw and Sneak Attack?

I had a "Yes" to the fist part of the question of weather Delayed Blast can be used with Sneak Attack. Now I wonder if it be taken up a notch or two.

Now one thing I keep in mind besides how to pull off a sneak attack besides circumstance (denied Dex to AC, surprise etc...) is number of times it can be done at any given time. This leads me to think on how this can be done.

With Flurry of Blast there's two options on how to pull it off. Multi targets up to the PC maximum amount, blast can be delayed either simultaneously as a group surprise or one right after the other catching them off by surprise as each ally is stuck followed by the other. The other is a concentrated Flurry on one target with each Delayed Blast happening every round.

For Many Throw would function much like the first option for Flurry of Blast.

Comment: Your question is really asking "How can I " rather than "Can I"...perhaps you should change it to read that way? Adding Sneak attack to multiple attacks generally can only be done without relying on Stealth.

Comment: You have a point. I came across another Kineticist Infusion called Snake, which basically allows you to make the Kinetic Blast a remote controlled as it make it way to the target. Plotting a multiple Blast to flank targets might be  way to make multiple sneak attacks in a round.

Comment: The most reliable way to get multiple sneak attacks in a round is with a melee attack, and a flanking buddy. Sneak attacks with a ranged attack are much harder to pull off, unless you have some sort of persistent invisibility or other way of being unseen over multiple attacks. The actual attack mechanism really doesn't enter into it.

Comment: Wouldn't Lethal Acrobatics and moving by hostiles threatened space and a Kinetic blast that hits multiple targets let you use Sneak Attacks?

Comment: Sure, that third party feat I've never heard of before would work for the FIRST attack (the feat says 'next attack'), at the cost of having to actually MOVE first, meaning you will only get one attack anyway.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by Flurry of Blast and Many Throw? I am unable to find any abilities with those names.

Comment: These are Infusions which modifies Kineticist's Kinetic Blast. Normally Kinetic Blast attacks once a round as a standard action. Flurry of Blast at Lv2 allows multiple attacks with Kinetic Blast, gaining one extra attack at specific levels but the number of attacks has a cap. Many Throw while similar to Flurry of Blast the limit of attacks is equal to your level. These are located here, http://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist/infusion-wild-talents/

Comment: Huh, weird, I searched for those, and got no hits...

Answer (score 1):

To apply [sneak attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue#TOC-Sneak-Attack) to any attack (Kinetic blast or otherwise), the target either needs to be flanked (which generally cannot happen with a ranged attack) or denied their Dex bonus. Assuming you are not applying any sort of condition to the target to deny them their Dex bonus, your attacker will need to be in some way undetected by the target, meaning either Invisible or Hidden.

Standard Invisibility (from spell or other ability) will generally be dispelled after an attack, meaning you will only be able to apply sneak attack to one attack. Greater Invisibility will persist after the first attack, but is a higher level spell.

If you are Hidden (meaning you have concealment, and have made a Stealth Check to hide, and beaten the target's Perception check), the target will be denied their Dex bonus from your attacks. In general, after the first attack, the target will be aware of you, and you will no longer be able to apply sneak attack. You can avoid revealing yourself by using the [Sniping](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/stealth#TOC-Sniping) option of the Stealth skill, which basically lets you make another Stealth check immediately at -20.

These rules will apply to almost all cases where you are making multiple attacks, pretty much regardless of how you get them. [Delay Blast](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/delay-blast/) doesn't change how the Blast actually works, apart from when it starts shooting. It doesn't change how many shots you make with the attack, or how far apart the shots might be, so the mechanics of using it with Sneak Attack will be the same, including timing of shots relative to each other. [Flurry of Blasts](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist/infusion-wild-talents/#TOC-Flurry-of-Blasts) and [Many Throw](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist/infusion-wild-talents/#TOC-Many-Throw) likewise don't change the mechanics of multiple attacks (although Many Throw ALMOST does, when the fluff text says you throw multiple objects at once).

Comment: Lethal Acrobatics (Rogue Talent), Skill Focus +3 (Acrobatics), Acrobat +1 (Trait), Boots of Elvenkind +5, and Belt of Incredible Dexterity +6. That's +15 to Acrobatics check before the d20 roll. Move act through hostiles' threatened space and Blast. Decent chances of sneak attack. While not a multi attack, it does give higher than average chance for a Sneak Attack. Add in feats like Point Blank Shot, Precise Shot, Shot on the Run, Parting Shot and Opening Volley make the stunt worth while with some flare.

Comment: None of that works with Flurry of Blast or Many Throw, which was the focus of your question...if you just want a reliable sneak attack, maybe you should alter the question?

Comment: The above mentioned was just an example of how attain sneak attack more freafquently from the previous comment. Yes it has nothing to do with focus attack. Just confirming other ways to legitimatly gain sneak attack. Sorry. Flurry of Blast and Many Throw may just work with Delayed Blast and to bypass the once per turn rule just set the effect to go off one round after the other within the 5 round limit of fear.

Comment: I think you are showing some deep misunderstanding about how Delayed Blast works...No, I don't believe that particular set of outcomes is achievable with those abilities.